# Django tastypie creating resources in two related models

Tags: python, django, rest, tastypie

I am having two models, I want to have a single api for model1 which when POSTed should create resource in model1 and model2, where model2 is related to model1 though a foreign key. Please find my models and resources for your reference,

```
class model1(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length = 60)


class model2(models.Model):
  var = models.BooleanField()
  modelid = models.ForeignKey(model1,related_name = 'amenities')


class model1Resource(ModelResource):
  amenities = fields.ToManyField(model2Resource,'amenities',full = True)  
  class  Meta:
     authorization = Authorization()
     queryset = model1.objects.all()
     resource_name = 'postrequirement'
     allowed_methods = ['post']

class model2Resource(ModelResource):
  class Meta:
     queryset = model2.objects.all()
     resource_name = 'getamenities'
     allowed_methods = ['get','post']
```

Answer (score 0):

use the Manager class:

```
class model2Manager(models.Manager):
    def createModel2WithAmenity(self, var, name):
        m2 = self.create(var=var)
        m2.modelid_set.create(name=name)

class model2:
    ....
    objects = model2Manager()
```

call model2.createModel2WithAmenity(var, name) to create the pair.